# Jprofiler command line utils return error

Tags: jprofiler

Command line utility jpenable returns error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher

We have CentOS 7 and Oracle Java 1.8

Did someone face such error?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/657219/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-com-install4j-runtime-launcher-launcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `[JProfiler install4j directory]/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar` directory is not present or damaged.

Comment: I have downloaded binaries for linux and I don't see any install4j directories or jars. Do you know is there any documentation or manuals about this?

Comment: Did you extract the .tar.gz file? Try `ls -la` in the extracted `jprofiler9` directory, it has to list an `.install4j` directory.

Comment: Thank you! It is hidden.